# Find all multiples of a number in given range in reverse order

Tags: c, objective-c

I have a problem set which requires me to print all the multiples of a number in given range in reverse order.

So far I have tried this but not sure it is optimized or not!

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>

@implementation TestObj

int main()
{
    int limit = 0;
    int divisor = 5;
    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&limit);

    printf("enter divisor : ");
    scanf("%d",&divisor);

    printf("Multiples of %d in reverse order till limit %d are : ",divisor, limit);
    for(int i = limit/divisor; i > 0 ; i--){
        printf("%d ",i*divisor);
    }

    return 0;
}

@end
```

Comment: Apart from `@implementation TestObj ... @end` (which is completely unnecessary because you never create an instance of that class) this code is plain old **C** and no Objective-C at all.

Comment: This question would be drastically better asked as a C language question.  Nothing about the `main()` function here is even remotely Objective-C.  The stuff outside the `main()` function is entirely irrelevant to the `main()` function, isn't used in this snippet, isn't going to be reviewed by anyone.  And on this site, the C tag *certainly* gets a lot more eyeballs than the Objective-C tag.  Moreover, you're not importing Foundation, so even if there were some fancy OOP solution to this problem... a *true* Objective-C review would be tough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication is not a very cheap operation.
Subtraction is much cheaper.
It will be a better and cleaner algorithm to start from the highest multiple,
and then keep subtracting until reaching 0:

```
int truncatedCount = limit / divisor;
int highestMultiple = truncatedCount * divisor;

for (int multiple = highestMultiple; multiple > 0; multiple -= divisor) {
    printf("%d ", multiple);
}
```

The improvements:

- multiplication replaced by subtractions
- more meaningful variable names (instead of `i`, for example)
- more conventional spacing (around operators and around `(...)` and `{ ... }`

Comment: I've always learned `i` is acceptable for an iterator, but only for an iterator. Did I learn wrong?

Comment: Just because it's accepted doesn't mean it's preferred.

Comment: Yes, `i` is often acceptable. But "acceptable" doesn't mean "great". I didn't criticize using `i`, but I saw an opportunity for improvement so I took it, and pointed it out as a recommendation. When there is an obvious better name than `i`, it's good to use it. Especially when `i` is not a regular run-of-the-mill counter from 0 to n but has more of a character as in this example.

Comment: This solution is good enough. I would like to take a test of time complexity and memory.

Answer (score 2):

> multiples of a number in given range in reverse

What I understood from that is, output the multiples of a given number for a given range in reverse. Say for example, if the number is 9 and the start range is 40 and end range is 65, the output will be: 63 54 45.

- Why limit?

  ```
  int limit = 0;
  ..............
  printf("enter a number : ");
  scanf("%d",&limit);
  ```

  Instead it must be named as `number`.
- Where is the given range?  I don't see that in the code.  Instead you are giving a divisor, which I am not sure is required or not.

  ```
  printf("enter divisor : ");
  scanf("%d",&divisor);
  ```
- You must also optimize the iteration by iterating only on the multiples after you obtain the upper range multiple.

  You must have code similar to this, then:

  ```
  int number, startRange, endRange;
  // feed the above variables by the user.
  for(endRange -= endRange % number; endRange >= startRange; endRange-=number) {
    printf("%d ", endRange);
  }
  ```

Comment: Please take more care of code formatting.

Comment: `int number` would be like stating grass is green. Non-descriptive.

Comment: Minimum range is the number itself. so starting from the number and go to the max limit range and print it reverse. This is the requirement.